# In PyParsing, how to use Combine() with a non-default joinString

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to refactor the `version_name` in the following parsing expression:

```
In [1]: from pyparsing import *

In [2]: version_code = "(" + Word(nums)("version_code") + ")"

In [3]: version_name = OneOrMore(~version_code + Word(printables)).setParseActio
   ...: n(lambda s,l,t: " ".join(t))("version_name")

In [4]: expression = version_name + version_code

In [5]: result = expression.parseString("1.0 beta (10)")

In [6]: result.asDict()
Out[6]: {'version_code': '10', 'version_name': '1.0 beta'}
```

Instead of using `.setParseAction(lambda s,l,t: " ".join(t))`, I would like to use `Combine()`. However, if I try to replace `version_name` with

```
In [7]: version_name = Combine(OneOrMore(~version_code + Word(printables)), join
   ...: String=" ")("version_name")
```

then upon re-running the test,

```
In [8]: expression = version_name + version_code

In [9]: result = expression.parseString("1.0 beta (10)")
```

I get a

```
ParseException: Expected "(" (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)
```

It seems like the parser is stopping with parsing the `version_name` after the `1.0` and not after `1.0 beta` as intended. Is there a way to refactor this with `Combine()` such that it still works?

Comment: `Combine` expects all matched tokens to be contiguous, unless `adjacent=False`. See https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.Combine-class.html

Comment: More discussion of Combine in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090980/need-help-understanding-pyparsing-behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following PaulMcG's comment, I added `adjacent=False` in the constructor of `Combine()`:

```
In [1]: from pyparsing import *

In [2]: version_code = "(" + Word(nums)("version_code") + ")"

In [3]: version_name = Combine(OneOrMore(~version_code + Word(printables)), joinString=" ", adjacent=False)("version_name")

In [4]: expression = version_name + version_code

In [5]: result = expression.parseString("1.0 beta (10)")

In [6]: result.asDict()
Out[6]: {'version_code': '10', 'version_name': '1.0 beta'}
```

The `version_name` now contains both words (`'1.0 beta'`) as desired.